# Is screen-sharing possible in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, screensharing

I'm working on making an application to share screen using react-native. I didn't found much lead in this quest, still I'm sharing what I found.

From an article I learned to develop a screen shot application (https://reactnativecode.com/take-screenshot-of-app-programmatically/), but this will only take screenshot of application, once I minimize application and open other app I can not take screenshto of that application.
First, I thought if I could take screenshot at 40fp/s then I could make a video out of it but for that, screenshot must work out of the application.

Next I found recording library for react-native here: https://github.com/ycswaves/react-native-screen-recorder so I tried to figure out a way to get real time feed of screen instead of saving it. But this solution also didn’t work, I didn’t found much information.

Then I tried to use webview react-native component to open a web application which already built and up and running and tried to open that web app in react-native application using webview to get screen stream, but this as well didn’t worked out.

I have these dependencies in my code

"dependencies": {

```
"react": "16.8.3",

"react-native": "0.59.9",

"react-native-minimize": "^1.0.12",

"react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.2",

"react-native-video": "^4.4.1",

"react-native-view-shot": "^2.6.0",

"react-native-webview": "^5.12.0"
```

}

Now I’m starting to think if screen-sharing is really possible in react-native or not. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can share the screen with Google Play's re-coding app.

Comment: Hi, can you please share some links? I'm can't find about Google Play's recoding app.

Comment: Hey, did you find anything related?

Comment: @edeesan no luck yet.